# Know Text overflowing from the span

Tags: javascript, html, css

content         width of inner span is auto ,
on span with class a text overflow ellipsis is applied, how can I know that text is overflowing

I want to know
Is text overflowing from span a

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to understand if the text is overflowing or not because there is no event for this to be fired

but you can check the width of the span and check if it's more than specific size you can understand if it's going to be overflowed